# Produce error message with http.get if a record isn't found in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have order data feeding into my app and populating my fields but if I enter an incorrect order number it doesn't throw an error just fills the fields with blank info.

```
$http.get('http://example.com/api' + query).success(function(data) {
    $scope.orders = data;
    console.log($scope.query);
    console.log(data);
    console.log($scope.orders);
```

There are many examples but without fully workable code, can anyone help with compiling a http.get function that will produce and error if an order doesn't match and display a "order not found" error.

```
$http.get('http://example.com').then(function(response){
    //the response from the server is now contained in 'response'
}, function(error) {
    //there was an error fetching from the server
});
```

Comment: I believe you should handle this server side, since it is a logical error and what you are currently getting is  empty values with a 200 success response (thus no error is thrown). Else, you should check the data in the response you get and if null, inform your user or in general do something.

Comment: You need either to process `query` variable and test with `if` if its all good. Otherwise you might wanna just throw an error on your backend and then you can use `function(error){}`.

Comment: Thanks mkaran. indeed, an empty order returns 200 OK in Postman but with an empty: data {}  So perhaps getting this sorted server side is the way to go, otherwise a function based around "result"   [
    [{
      "reason": "Invalid Order",
      "action": "getOrder",
      "data": {},
      "result": "FAIL"
    }
  ]```

Answer (score 0):

If the API returns the empty results with the `status - 200 OK` means follow the below code to throw the error Or else ask the server team to throw the 404 status code for match not founds on your API itself.

```
$http.get('http://example.com').then(function(response){
    if(response.data==''){
        //Throw error message as 'Order not found'
    }
    //the response from the server is now contained in 'response'
}, function(error){
    if(error.status=='404'){
        //Throw error message as 'Order not found'
    }
    //there was an error fetching from the server
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, you can check whether you response.data has something or nothing.

Below is the code for the same...

```
 $http.get('http://example.com').then(function(response){
            if(!response.data){
               // here you can throw error message 'Order not foun
            }
     }, function(error){
         //there was an error fetching from the server
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Derived promises are created by **returning** or **throwing** to the handler functions.

```
var httpPromise = $http.get('http://example.com');

var derivedPromise = httpPromise.then( function onSuccess(response) {
     if (response.data.length == 0) {
         response.status = 404;
         response.statusText = "Not Found -- Zero records";
         //throw to chain rejection
         throw response;
     } else {
         //return to chain response
         return response;
     };
});
```

The above example **converts** a response with zero length data to a rejection.

Be aware that the `.sucesss` method **ignores** return (or thrown) values. The `.sucesss` and `.error` methods are unsuitable for chaining and have been deprecated.

> ### Deprecation Notice<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.